# print() clears console with pytesseract

Tags: python, spyder

I followed a tutorial on a webpage to code a program to recognize text in images, the code it's very straightforward and it's the following.

```
    import cv2, pytesseract
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

    img = cv2.imread('test_image.jpeg')
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    print(text)
    print('done')
```

where "test_image.jpeg" is an image (with some text) placed in the same folder where the program has been saved.

I already installed cv2 and pytesseract and the installation was successful as they are in the list of modules installed.

But when I run the program, it clears the console (working on Spyder, Python 3.8) and it just prints 'done'.

I've made some checks and the problem is the line "print(text)", when it runs it, it clears the console.

I tried to use another output function, sys.stdout.write(text), and it does the same thing.

I tried to uninstall numpy and cv2 and reinstalled them.

I checked if text was a string with "print(type(text))" and it says string.

I checked in the Variable Explorer if just before printing the 'text' variable had the right text in it, and it had it, so everything in "background" should be ok.

Now I'm thinking I might just missing something easy that I can't see, could you help me? Thank you! :)

Comment: If you see the content inside, `text` may end with a series of linefeeds or some other control character.

Comment: ^ try `print(repr(text))`, that should show if any control characters are there. If i remember right, tesseract might do something like print an absurd amount of newlines, like tevemadar said.

Comment: I tried and yes, there were four \n and one \x0c, and I removed them and it's ok, thanks :).
I have a friend who tried the same code yesterday (on Visual Studio Code) and it worked fine for him. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in the comment you can solve the problem printing repr(text)

```
    print(repr(text))
```

You can notice that there are (at least in my case) a lot of \n and one \x0c, that is a sort of 'new page' escape sequence. These come from the way pytesseract works.
So the easier way to fix the problem I found is to delete them through

```
    text = text[:-5]
```

The number of escape sequences depends on the image, but you could create a function to identify and delete them, for example, starting from the end, you delete every escape sequence you find.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer by Matte, you can check for the existence of escape sequences by printing

```
print(repr(text))
```

To get rid of the escape sequence you have two options:

1. You `strip` the OCR result to remove all whitespace at the beginning or end of the string. This works regardless of how many `\n` or `\x0c` characters there are at the end.

   `text = text.strip()`
2. You change or remove the page separator used by tesseract (by default this is `\x0c`, see https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ.html#tesseract-400).

   `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="-c page_separator=''")`